# How to minify a JSON text file with grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, uglifyjs

I need to minify a set of JSON files (language files) with Grunt/grunt-contrib-uglify:

```javascript
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
        build: {
            src: 'src/main/app/resources/locales/*/*.json',
            dest: 'target/resources/locales/*/*.json'
        }
    }
});
```

What I'm getting is:

```
Files: src/main/app/resources/locales/en/messages.json -> target/*/*.json
Minifying with UglifyJS...Reading src/main/app/resources/locales/en/messages.json...OK
>> Uglifying source "src/main/app/resources/locales/en/messages.json" failed.
Warning: Uglification failed. Use --force to continue.
```

I'm starting to wonder, does uglify work on pure JSON files, or is it intended for JavaScript source files only? The JSON file is surely well formed, it runs in the application in its non-minimized form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `grunt-json-minify` (as indicated in user2806181's answer) works OK (thanks, by the way), but it only modifies files in place. Inspired by the answer, I've found one that's a bit more advanced: [grunt-minjson](https://github.com/shama/grunt-minjson):

```javascript
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    minjson: {
        build: {
            files: { 
                'target/locales/en/messages.json':
                    'resource/locales/en/messages.json'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But grunt-json-minify is able to work on many files in one run without concatenating them, while grunt-minjson will concatenate all files (which is most likely not what you want for JSON files).

Answer (score 2):

I guess UglifyJS does not work on pure JSON, because its not valid javascript.

Take a look at this link: https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/156

But there are several grunt-plugins you can use, for example: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-json-minify